# The data from Firestore database is not displayed in the tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Swift and Firestore database to implement an app like Twitter.
I want to add sweet (it's like tweet) when button is clicked to the database. And then display it in the tableview.
The data is added to the database. But is not displayed in the tableview. So when I run an app I see empty tableview.
Please help!!

TableViewController file:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var db:Firestore!

    var sweetArray = [Sweet]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        db = Firestore.firestore()

        loadData()
    }

    func loadData() {
        db.collection("sweets").getDocuments() {
            querySnapshot, error in

            if let error = error {

                print("Error loading documents to the db: \(error.localizedDescription)")

            } else {

                self.sweetArray = querySnapshot!.documents.flatMap({Sweet(dictionary: $0.data())})

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func composeSweet(_ sender: Any) {

           let composeAlert = UIAlertController(title: "New Sweet", message: "Enter your name and message", preferredStyle: .alert)

           composeAlert.addTextField { (textField:UITextField) in
               textField.placeholder = "Your name"
           }

           composeAlert.addTextField { (textField:UITextField) in
               textField.placeholder = "Your message"
           }

           composeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
           composeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in

            if let name = composeAlert.textFields?.first?.text, let content = composeAlert.textFields?.last?.text {
                let newSweet = Sweet(name: name, content: content, timeStamp: Date())

                var ref:DocumentReference? = nil
                ref = self.db.collection("sweets").addDocument(data: newSweet.dictionary) {
                    error in

                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error adding document: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
                    }
                }
            }
           }))

           self.present(composeAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

       }

       override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
       }

       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return sweetArray.count
       }

       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let sweet = sweetArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(sweet.name) : \(sweet.content)"

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(sweet.timeStamp)"

        return cell
       }

}
```

Sweet file:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

protocol DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct Sweet {
    var name: String
    var content: String
    var timeStamp: Date

    var dictionary:[String:Any] {
        return [
            "name": name,
            "content": content,
            "timeStamp": timeStamp
        ]
    }
}

extension Sweet:DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
            let content = dictionary["content"] as? String,
            let timeStamp = dictionary["timeStamp"] as? Date else {return nil}

        self.init(name: name, content: content, timeStamp: timeStamp)
    }
}
```

My storyboards:
[image]

My running app:

[image]

Comment: Did you check if there is data in `sweetArray` after fetching.

Comment: @Frankenstein I printed out sweetArray in loadData func, after flatMap method, and sweetArray is empty

Comment: What about `querySnapshot`?

Comment: @Frankenstein Printed out querySnapshot and it's <FIRQuerySnapshot: 0x7fa70f543000>. print(querySnapshot.documents) prints out 4 snapshots that I have in my database right now.

Comment: That means you need to fix your parsing.

Comment: The reason you don't know what's causing the issue is because of your use of the guard statement in the extension - it's too generic. That guard statement tests three different fields and if any of them don't match your firebase data, it silently fails. If you handle each one separately, it will become very obvious what the issue is. `let name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? "Name Field Not Found!"` and then `let name = dictionary["content"] as? String ?? "Content Field Not Found!"`. More than likely one of your fields has a different name or upper/lowercase; *Name* vs *name* for example.

Comment: @Jay Thank you so much!! The problem was with timeStamp field that type is Data. So I removed timeStamp at all and it worked! Actually this small project I created to fix the same issue in bigger project where I have the same Data model. In that big project I have fields only of String type, so I just removed guard let statement, handled each field separately and it also worked! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Excellent! I added an answer as this seems to be a common issue with the guard statement not catching errors as a more fine-grained level.

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide a specific answer but I can explain how to find what the issue is.

While adding guard statements to protect your code is awesome, it can also lead to issues not being handled appropriately.

Take this piece of code from your question for example

```
guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
            let content = dictionary["content"] as? String,
            let timeStamp = dictionary["timeStamp"] as? Date else {return nil}
```

As you can see if there's some issue with name, content or timestamp, the guard will catch it - however, returning nil means it silently fails with no indication of the problem.

Suppose for example, that a field name was accidentally called Name instead of name - well, that's going to fail but you'd never know it.

I suggest handling fields separately to catch specific problems. Like this

```
let name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? "name field not found"
let name = dictionary["content"] as? String ?? "content field not found"
let name = dictionary["timesStamp"] as? Date ?? "timestamp field not found"
```

This is called nil coalescing and will substitute a default value in case of nil. By then examining the incoming data, you can find the document that caused the issue. You could also do this

```
guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String else { //handle the error }
```

in either case, you then have more data about the nature of the failure.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have data in `querySnapshot` but empty in `sweetArray` which means only one this your are parsing and mapping the data received into `structs` incorrectly. Modify this line to fix your issue:

```swift
self.sweetArray = querySnapshot!.documents.flatMap({Sweet(dictionary: $0.data())})
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you please advise what can I do?

Comment: Use the correct parsing according to your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

private var refernceCollection: CollectionReference!

database = Firestore.firestore()
refernceCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection(kMessages)

func fetchData() {

```
    refernceCollection.addSnapshotListener{ snapshots, error in
        
        if error != nil {
            print("error --->>")
        } else {
            guard let snap = snapshots else { return }
            var arrUser:[MDLMessages] = []
            for documet in snap.documents {
                let data = documet.data()
                let message = data["message"] as? String ?? "This message was deleted"
                let time = data["time"] as? Date ?? Date.now
                let documentId = documet.documentID
                let userId = data["userId"] as? String ?? ""
                let details = MDLMessages(message: message, time: time, documentId: documentId, userId: userId)
                arrUser.append(details)
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.arrMessages = arrUser
                self.tblChatDetails.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).